# I cannot figure out what html img src to use

Tags: html, image

I have a Django app, coding in VS Code. I haven't added any JavaScript. No React, no Angular, nothing like that. I'm using Bootstrap if that matters. I'm trying to add an image to my home page, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why it returns 404 error.

Here's my folder tree:

[image: Folder Tree]

And the snippet concerning the photo:

```
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-0">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img src="../../media/rockbrow.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="PLACEHOLDER" />
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The page I'm adding the image on is "home.html".

I have tried:

- `src="../../media/rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="../media/rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="../../../media/rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="/portfolio_site/mysite/portfolio/media/rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="/mysite/portfolio/media/rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="/portfolio/media/rockbrow.jpg"`

I tried moving the image into the same folder as home.html and using:

- `src="rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="./rockbrow.jpg"`
- `src="../portfolio/rockbrow.jpg"`

I am able to open the image in VS Code, Paint, Photoshop, everything. It is not corrupted.

I tried viewing in Firefox and Chrome. I tried disabling and re-enabling caching. I tried restarting the app. I tried re-migrating the Django app (despite this having nothing to do with the database).

Opening the src in another tab just shows "127.0.0.1:8000/[whatever src path I typed]", and I don't know how that helps me.

This is literally as simple as img tag gets. Is it because of Django? Did I somehow miss the correct src path? It's a 404 Error, but I do not understand how it's not finding it.

Comment: Im no Django expert but arent you supposed to use the `static` directory for this? [`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Oh my GODDD. I forgot about that.  Yeah I think that's the issue, I'll do that and come back. Wasted like 2 hours because I forgot static directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CodeSpirit for reminding me... The problem was that I needed to use the Django static directory, and put the images in there to reference them using `src="{% static 'portfolio/rockbrow.jpg' %}"`.